# Capacity loss in a battery

Tags: solid-state-physics, charge, batteries, electrochemistry

It is often said how to the health of a battery gets worse as you charge and discharge it through numerous cycles. So, the maximum available cell capacity a battery can have after recharging reduces over time.

I am wondering if there is an equation to quantitatively describe this phenomena. I came across this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1051/e3sconf/20198701026) which gave this:

[image]

I am only a high school student and don't really understand the paper that well. I was wondering if someone could tell me if this mathematical model describes what I'm discussing or if it's just describing something else like the SOC (state of charge).

Answer (score 0):

Here are the basics.

The equation you cite presumes that the chemical reactions by which a battery self-discharges over time are *thermally activated* without any specification of the exact chemical pathway by which those processes occur.

But a complete and useful model of self-discharge requires an understanding of those chemical pathways which is specific to each different battery chemistry which the invocation of an Arrhenius equation does not furnish.

Once you get the chance to study *electrochemistry*, you will probably find the answers to your questions.

Comment: Even if the Arrhenius equation cited by the paper is not a generalized equation for all batteries, can we still use it to describe the degradation of cell capacity if accuracy is not a worry? Specifically degradation of the maximum capacity of a battery.

Comment: Probably. I would defer to the experts!